# Different results for certain group if filter is applied in user function vs. no filter

Tags: r

I have a data set which consists out of multiple describing variables (type, origin etc.) and timestamps per observation of an item. The timestamps specify different states reached by the item.

The Items are parts of different system-units, which are identified by an ID. A unit must consist of at least one item but there is no upper limit.

A much simplified example data set is:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(10)

data <- data.frame(ID=paste(c(rep(2010,times=250),rep(2011,times=200),rep(2012,times=300)),"_",sprintf("%02d", sample(50,replace=TRUE,size=750))),
                   year=c(rep(2010,times=250),rep(2011,times=200),rep(2012,times=300)),
                   Cat=sample(c("A","B","C","D","E"),replace=TRUE,size=750)) %>% 
  mutate(Time_1=strptime(paste(year,"-01-01 01:",c(sprintf("%02d",rep(59,times=750))),":",sample(2,replace=TRUE,size=750),sep=""),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
         Time_2=strptime(paste(year,"-01-01 02:",c(sprintf("%02d",sample(0,replace=TRUE,size=750))),":",sample(59,replace=TRUE,size=750),sep=""),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Some items are considered relevant and some items are considered irrelevant. The following lookup-table gives information about that:

```
lookup <- data.frame(Cat=c("A","B","C","D","E"),
                     Relevant=c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE))


df <- data %>% 
  left_join(lookup)
```

I wrote a function which does the following:

1. Applies a filter if passed as an argument
2. Adds a column with the smallest timestamp per unit only considering relevant items
3. Checks if the time difference between time1 and the smallest timestamp per unit matches a condition
4. Returns the result as summary

For the example data set the function would look like:

```
foo <- function(data,Filter=FALSE) {
  
  new_column <- data %>% 
  filter(Relevant) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%  
  slice_min(order_by = Time_2,with_ties=FALSE) %>% 
  select(ID,Time_2) %>% 
  rename("Time_2_mod"="Time_2") %>% 
  ungroup()
  
  Obj <- data %>% 
    {if (isFALSE(Filter)) .  else filter(.,eval(rlang::parse_expr(Filter)))} %>% 
    left_join(new_column) %>% 
    mutate(check=Time_2_mod-Time_1 < 90) %>% 
    group_by(year) %>% 
    summarise(count_checked=sum(check, na.rm=TRUE))
  
  return(Obj)
  
}
```

Now, the output without filter is:

```
> foo(df)
Joining, by = "ID"
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   year count_checked
* <dbl>         <int>
1  2010           175
2  2011           149
3  2012           245
```

With filter applied for some of the years I get a different result:

```
> foo(df,Filter="year==2010")
Joining, by = "ID"
# A tibble: 1 x 2
   year count_checked
* <dbl>         <int>
1  2010           232
```

```
> foo(df,Filter="year==2011")
Joining, by = "ID"
# A tibble: 1 x 2
   year count_checked
* <dbl>         <int>
1  2011           173
```

```
> foo(df,Filter="year==2012")
Joining, by = "ID"
# A tibble: 1 x 2
   year count_checked
* <dbl>         <int>
1  2012           245
```

**Why is that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me quite a while to figure it out and I got to the answer by deconstructing the function step by step. The key was to look at the result of the difference in `mutate(check=Time_2_mod-Time_1 < 90)`. So I changed it to `mutate(check=Time_2_mod-Time_1)` followed by `head(10)` to only see the first 10 rows.

Function now is:

```
foo_2 <- function(data,Filter=FALSE) {
  
  new_column <- data %>% 
    filter(Relevant) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>%  
    slice_min(order_by = Time_2,with_ties=FALSE) %>% 
    select(ID,Time_2) %>% 
    rename("Time_2_mod"="Time_2") %>% 
    ungroup()
  
  Obj <- data %>% 
    {if (isFALSE(Filter)) .  else filter(.,eval(rlang::parse_expr(Filter)))} %>% 
    left_join(new_column) %>% 
    mutate(check=Time_2_mod-Time_1) %>% 
    head(10)
  
  return(Obj)
  
}
```

Result without filtering:

```
> foo_2(df)
Joining, by = "ID"
          ID year Cat              Time_1              Time_2 Relevant          Time_2_mod    check
1  2010 _ 43 2010   C 2010-01-01 01:59:02 2010-01-01 02:00:40    FALSE                <NA>  NA secs
2  2010 _ 09 2010   B 2010-01-01 01:59:02 2010-01-01 02:00:49    FALSE 2010-01-01 02:00:18  76 secs
3  2010 _ 10 2010   E 2010-01-01 01:59:02 2010-01-01 02:00:55     TRUE 2010-01-01 02:00:49 107 secs
4  2010 _ 48 2010   B 2010-01-01 01:59:02 2010-01-01 02:00:47    FALSE 2010-01-01 02:00:13  71 secs
5  2010 _ 12 2010   C 2010-01-01 01:59:02 2010-01-01 02:00:54    FALSE 2010-01-01 02:00:03  61 secs
6  2010 _ 08 2010   D 2010-01-01 01:59:01 2010-01-01 02:00:45    FALSE 2010-01-01 02:00:19  78 secs
7  2010 _ 39 2010   C 2010-01-01 01:59:01 2010-01-01 02:00:24    FALSE 2010-01-01 02:00:21  80 secs
8  2010 _ 19 2010   E 2010-01-01 01:59:01 2010-01-01 02:00:21     TRUE 2010-01-01 02:00:21  80 secs
9  2010 _ 24 2010   B 2010-01-01 01:59:01 2010-01-01 02:00:51    FALSE                <NA>  NA secs
10 2010 _ 15 2010   D 2010-01-01 01:59:01 2010-01-01 02:00:43    FALSE 2010-01-01 02:00:02  61 secs
```

And with the filters applied:

```
> foo_2(df,Filter="year==2010")
Joining, by = "ID"
          ID year Cat              Time_1              Time_2 Relevant          Time_2_mod
1  2010 _ 43 2010   C 2010-01-01 01:59:02 2010-01-01 02:00:40    FALSE                <NA>
2  2010 _ 09 2010   B 2010-01-01 01:59:02 2010-01-01 02:00:49    FALSE 2010-01-01 02:00:18
3  2010 _ 10 2010   E 2010-01-01 01:59:02 2010-01-01 02:00:55     TRUE 2010-01-01 02:00:49
4  2010 _ 48 2010   B 2010-01-01 01:59:02 2010-01-01 02:00:47    FALSE 2010-01-01 02:00:13
5  2010 _ 12 2010   C 2010-01-01 01:59:02 2010-01-01 02:00:54    FALSE 2010-01-01 02:00:03
6  2010 _ 08 2010   D 2010-01-01 01:59:01 2010-01-01 02:00:45    FALSE 2010-01-01 02:00:19
7  2010 _ 39 2010   C 2010-01-01 01:59:01 2010-01-01 02:00:24    FALSE 2010-01-01 02:00:21
8  2010 _ 19 2010   E 2010-01-01 01:59:01 2010-01-01 02:00:21     TRUE 2010-01-01 02:00:21
9  2010 _ 24 2010   B 2010-01-01 01:59:01 2010-01-01 02:00:51    FALSE                <NA>
10 2010 _ 15 2010   D 2010-01-01 01:59:01 2010-01-01 02:00:43    FALSE 2010-01-01 02:00:02
           check
1        NA mins
2  1.266667 mins
3  1.783333 mins
4  1.183333 mins
5  1.016667 mins
6  1.300000 mins
7  1.333333 mins
8  1.333333 mins
9        NA mins
10 1.016667 mins
```

```
> foo_2(df,Filter="year==2011")
Joining, by = "ID"
          ID year Cat              Time_1              Time_2 Relevant          Time_2_mod
1  2011 _ 38 2011   D 2011-01-01 01:59:01 2011-01-01 02:00:17    FALSE 2011-01-01 02:00:23
2  2011 _ 25 2011   B 2011-01-01 01:59:02 2011-01-01 02:00:27    FALSE 2011-01-01 02:00:07
3  2011 _ 22 2011   C 2011-01-01 01:59:01 2011-01-01 02:00:58    FALSE 2011-01-01 02:00:20
4  2011 _ 11 2011   C 2011-01-01 01:59:01 2011-01-01 02:00:57    FALSE 2011-01-01 02:00:36
5  2011 _ 35 2011   C 2011-01-01 01:59:01 2011-01-01 02:00:03    FALSE 2011-01-01 02:00:41
6  2011 _ 29 2011   A 2011-01-01 01:59:01 2011-01-01 02:00:44     TRUE 2011-01-01 02:00:04
7  2011 _ 28 2011   A 2011-01-01 01:59:01 2011-01-01 02:00:25     TRUE 2011-01-01 02:00:13
8  2011 _ 34 2011   A 2011-01-01 01:59:01 2011-01-01 02:00:46     TRUE 2011-01-01 02:00:03
9  2011 _ 01 2011   B 2011-01-01 01:59:01 2011-01-01 02:00:43    FALSE 2011-01-01 02:00:19
10 2011 _ 08 2011   E 2011-01-01 01:59:01 2011-01-01 02:00:07     TRUE 2011-01-01 02:00:07
           check
1  1.366667 mins
2  1.083333 mins
3  1.316667 mins
4  1.583333 mins
5  1.666667 mins
6  1.050000 mins
7  1.200000 mins
8  1.033333 mins
9  1.300000 mins
10 1.100000 mins
```

```
> foo_2(df,Filter="year==2012")
Joining, by = "ID"
          ID year Cat              Time_1              Time_2 Relevant          Time_2_mod    check
1  2012 _ 15 2012   E 2012-01-01 01:59:02 2012-01-01 02:00:29     TRUE 2012-01-01 02:00:26  84 secs
2  2012 _ 18 2012   A 2012-01-01 01:59:01 2012-01-01 02:00:01     TRUE 2012-01-01 02:00:01  60 secs
3  2012 _ 08 2012   A 2012-01-01 01:59:02 2012-01-01 02:00:21     TRUE 2012-01-01 02:00:21  79 secs
4  2012 _ 10 2012   D 2012-01-01 01:59:02 2012-01-01 02:00:23    FALSE 2012-01-01 02:00:10  68 secs
5  2012 _ 03 2012   C 2012-01-01 01:59:02 2012-01-01 02:00:20    FALSE 2012-01-01 02:00:12  70 secs
6  2012 _ 02 2012   B 2012-01-01 01:59:02 2012-01-01 02:00:25    FALSE 2012-01-01 02:00:42 100 secs
7  2012 _ 46 2012   C 2012-01-01 01:59:01 2012-01-01 02:00:23    FALSE 2012-01-01 02:00:34  93 secs
8  2012 _ 22 2012   E 2012-01-01 01:59:01 2012-01-01 02:00:45     TRUE 2012-01-01 02:00:24  83 secs
9  2012 _ 27 2012   D 2012-01-01 01:59:01 2012-01-01 02:00:56    FALSE 2012-01-01 02:00:27  86 secs
10 2012 _ 35 2012   D 2012-01-01 01:59:02 2012-01-01 02:00:32    FALSE 2012-01-01 02:00:24  82 secs
```

You know will easily recognize that the units in the last column `check`seem to depend on the year filtered. Which is only half the truth. The difference of two date/times is a difftime. And if no unit is given, the function will choose "auto"matically

> a suitable set of units is chosen, the largest possible (excluding "weeks") in which all the absolute differences are greater than one.

[Source](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/difftime.html)

So that is what produced the inconsistency in results. It was not the filter but that the difftimes for the years 2010 and 2011 were at least one minute and therefor minutes were used as unit while in the year 2012 there was at least one difftime which was less than one minute so seconds was used as unit.

To fix that behaviour `mutate(check=Time_2_mod-Time_1 < 90)` should be changed to `mutate(check=difftime(Time_2_mod,Time_1,units="secs") <90)`

```
foo_3 <- function(data,Filter=FALSE) {
  
  new_column <- data %>% 
  filter(Relevant) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%  
  slice_min(order_by = Time_2,with_ties=FALSE) %>% 
  select(ID,Time_2) %>% 
  rename("Time_2_mod"="Time_2") %>% 
  ungroup()
  
  Obj <- data %>% 
    {if (isFALSE(Filter)) .  else filter(.,eval(rlang::parse_expr(Filter)))} %>% 
    left_join(new_column) %>% 
    mutate(check=difftime(Time_2_mod,Time_1,units="secs") <90) %>% 
    group_by(year) %>% 
    summarise(count_checked=sum(check, na.rm=TRUE))
  
  return(Obj)
  
}
```

This returns consistent results with and without filtering.

```
> foo_3(df)
Joining, by = "ID"
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   year count_checked
* <dbl>         <int>
1  2010           175
2  2011           149
3  2012           245
```

```
> foo_3(df,Filter="year==2010") 
Joining, by = "ID"
# A tibble: 1 x 2
   year count_checked
* <dbl>         <int>
1  2010           175
```

```
> foo_3(df,Filter="year==2011")
Joining, by = "ID"
# A tibble: 1 x 2
   year count_checked
* <dbl>         <int>
1  2011           149
```

```
> foo_3(df,Filter="year==2012")
Joining, by = "ID"
# A tibble: 1 x 2
   year count_checked
* <dbl>         <int>
1  2012           245
```